# dispatch_async doesn't work as advertised

Tags: objective-c, ios7, dispatch-async

I'm still pretty green with iOS, but the code below seems like it should work. I have a bunch of work to do in the background so a "busy indicator" is supposed to be shown to the user while the work is done. But what happens is the busy indicator does not appear for several seconds. It only appears once most of the work (but not all) has completed.

```
- (void) fetchDataTest {

    // next line will create and display a busy indicator
    __block MRProgressOverlayView *overlay = [MRProgressOverlayView showOverlayAddedTo:self.view title:@"Loading…" mode:MRProgressOverlayViewModeIndeterminate animated:YES];

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_LOW, 0), ^(void) {

        [self fetchData];

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void) {
            [overlay hide:YES];
        });
    });
}
```

I have lots of logging (not shown above) that runs so slowly I can watch the output log (including thread ids) and see overlay has been created and background work started - yet no overlay on my device appears for several seconds.

How can I get the overlay to appear immediately?

Comment: Maybe this function wasn't called from the main queue?

Comment: Try changing your dispatch queue priority.

Comment: I wonder if the problem is that fetchDataTest is called from viewWillAppear? Perhaps the "UI" just isn't ready...

Comment: I (we) got around this problem using performSelector:withObject: afterDelay. This gave the progress overlay enough time to display itself before the UI thread got blocked (then I just left the rest of the code as is). The user gets and animated "app is busy" widget and I don't have to re-architect/rewrite the code.

Answer (score 0):

Observations:

1. you shouldn't use GCD to make synchronous data fetches look asynchronous — just use the asynchronous fetches directly. They're much better for overall scheduling and for battery life;
2. it's the bit that occurs before the `dispatch_async`s that isn't happening, not the stuff within them;
3. Jack Wu's guess is probably right: on what thread or queue is `fetchDataTest` being performed? It should be the main queue.

On the last point: UIKit is not generally thread safe. With a few exceptions, you should always use it from the main queue. That's a large part of what the main queue is for nowadays: all user interaction. Then heavy work should be passed off elsewhere.

Comment: viewWillAppear calls fetchDataTest - thread num is 1. Main thread?

There is a lot going on in fetchDataTest, http requests, parsing, writes to core data. When you say asynchronous fetches, what api calls are you referring to?
 Thanks.

Comment: Adding some more logging - it seems only after viewWillAppear returns will the progress overlay display